# How get the next and previuos day in java Calendar?

Tags: java, calendar

How get the next and previuos day in java Calendar?

Comment: get today and add/subtract one day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either user the Calendar class like icyrock said or use Joda Time. You can see examples of Joda time [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html). I recommend using Joda time highly.

Jodatime code snippet:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(date); //the date you want to add days to
 Date addedDate = dt.plusDays(daysToAdd).toDate(); //the added days date
 Date subtractedDate = dt.minusDays(daysToMinus).toDate(); //the subtracted days date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
```